# update the first two words in a given sentence to lower case in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there any way to modify the first two words in a given sentence to lower case in excel.

Ex:

```
false RAGweed triggered histamine release IgE, QN, blood
```

This should be updated as

```
"false ragweed triggered histamine release IgE, QN, blood'.
```

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 1):

### Two Words Lower Case

- Until someone posts an elegant solution, play with the following where the 'star of the show' is

  ```
  =FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)
  ```

  (the position of the second space).

**Comma**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)),LOWER(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)),LOWER(A1))
```

**Semi-colon**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ";A1;FIND(" ";A1)+1));LOWER(LEFT(A1;FIND(" ";A1;FIND(" ";A1)+1)))&RIGHT(A1;LEN(A1)-FIND(" ";A1;FIND(" ";A1)+1));LOWER(A1))
```